# Trim first several characters from given lines in bash

Tags: shell

I need to process a large file.

The inputs are 
(1) input1: a text file that needs to be trimmed, for example:

```
acefgdx
cefgfx
aa
efgdx
b
afefgdx
```

(2) input2: a text file that include information about what to be trimmed and from which line. For example:

```
2,1
1,2
2,6
```

The above examples ask to trim: 
first 2 characters from 1st line 
first 1 characters from 2nd line 
first 2 characters from 6th line 
...

So the output file will be:

```
efgdx
efgfx
aa
efgdx
b
efgdx
```

I can achieve my goal using a loop such as

```
 while read lines 
 do
   n=`echo $lines|awk -F: '{print $1}'`; 
   m=`echo $lines|awk -F: '{print $2}'`; 
   sed -e  "${n}s/^.\{,$m\}//" input1 > input1_new
   mv input1_new input1
 done < input2
```

Since my input1 and input2 files are large, I'd like to know if there's any more efficient solution for it. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do add 3 simple things in your question. 1st: Sample of input, 2nd: Sample of output, 3rd: your tried code. So kindly edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Your question is Good and I have edited it but your tried code is missing, so please post it first so that your question is NOT closed, kindly do add your tried code and let us know then.

Comment: Thank you again @RavinderSingh13! I just posted my tried code.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is well suited to this task.  Something like:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{k[$2]=$1; next} 
    {print substr($0, k[FNR] + 1)}' FS=, indexes FS='' file-to-trim
```

This is a common idiom in awk: building an index with the first file, and then processing the second file using that index.  If the file is large, building the index in memory may become an issue, so you can do something like:

```
awk '!p { getline m < "indexes"; split(m, a, ","); p = 1}
    NR == a[2] {p=0} 1 { k = p ? 0 : a[1]; print substr($0, k + 1)}' file-to-trim
```

Note that the second version absolutely relies on the index file being sorted on the 2nd column.  If it is not, pre-process the file to make it so.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, honestly from last 30 mins first solution of yours is exactly I had done and its in draft state was waiting for user's attempts, no worries, cheers and ++ve

Comment: Thank you @william-pursell! Your second version is exactly what I need.

Comment: @william-pursell, I'm trying to use a variable for the "indexes" in your 2nd version by the following code, but it didn't work. Can you help me to fix it? Thank you!      awk -v indexes="$input2" '!p { getline m < "indexes"; split(m, a, ","); p = 1}
    NR == a[2] {p=0} 1 { k = p ? 0 : a[1]; print substr($0, k + 1)}' file-to-trim

Comment: @WenWang Just drop the quotes: `getline m < indexes`

Comment: @william-pursell I appreciate your help -- everything works like a charm!